# Google Chrome: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: google-chrome

I recently updated Google Chrome to 86.0.4240.75 and I keep getting this error message:

```
net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

I'm on a fixed local IPv4 (192.168.x) and fixed IPv6. The error appears randomly at the rate of about 1 each minute; browsing is becoming difficult, many connections are cut short (leading to blank screen and aborted POST).
ssh connection are steady.
I'm running Ubuntu 19.10

Any idea of how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score -2):

i think its som kind of glitch in the newest version, this issue happends on windows two. I think the fastes way to fix it right now is to install a older version of chrome or change to Edge. sorry if it didn't help

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: greg, you are not allone. same at my ubuntu

Comment: I somehow run into this problem when I start a docker container. When I restart the system it works again.